# Calculus, on shell method and finding Volume

Tags: calculus

Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume V generated by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified axis.
$y = 32 − x^2$, $y = x^2$;   about $x = 4$

$$V=?$$

So far, I got $\dfrac {1280\pi}{3}$, but my homework says it's wrong. I did $V=\int\limits_0^4 2\pi rh \,\mathrm dx$, which got me to $V=\int\limits_0^4 2\pi (4-x)(32-2x^2)\,\mathrm dx$, hence $\dfrac {1280\pi}{3}$.

Comment: What have you tried? We're not here to do your HW for you.

Comment: So far, I got 1280pi/3, but my homework says it's wrong.
I did V=∫[0,4] 2πrh dx, which got me to V=∫[0,4] 2π(4-x)(32-2x^2)dx, hence 1280pi/3. I got that answer wrong, and I've been stuck on that.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the contents of the above comment to your post. Do not expect us to have to ask you about what you have tried. Also, please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: **Hint:** A plot of the *two curves* shows they enclose an area between $x\in[-4..4]$ .  @VigneshR .  You have not generated enough volumn.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: This hint is based on method described in page 414 of calculus by Robert A. Adams.For cylindrical shells rotated about y axis(where x=0):

$$V=2\pi \int ^b_a x\big(g(x)-f(x)\big)dx$$

$f(x)=32-x^2$

$g(x)=x^2$

The curves intersect on $(x, y)= (4, 16)$, and they rotate about $x=4$, so interval is $[b=4, a=-4]$.You must get $V=64\pi$.